# log file doesn't exist when logging message using syslog

Tags: c, linux, syslog

```
#include <syslog.h>

void log_msg(char *name, int priority, const char *format)
{
    va_list vl;

    openlog(name, 0, LOG_DAEMON);
    va_start(vl, format);
    vsyslog(log_class[priority], format, vl);
    va_end(vl);
    closelog();
}
```

I use this code to log all message when running my program in openwrt backfire 10.03. but I can't find any log under `/var/log`  .
it some thing wrong in my code ! knowing that I don't find the config file of syslog demons in `/etc/syslog.conf`

Comment: Use of char or short as the second argument to `va_arg` is invariably an error: these types always promote up to one of signed int or unsigned int, and float converts to double.

Comment: Please look http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter9/stdarg.html

Comment: Based on the title of your question I assume you didn't read the [man page for `openlog`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/openlog) particulary this part: `The string pointed to by ident is prepended to every message`. So a *new* log file won't appear, it just prepends a message

Comment: Have you figured out how to enable syslog in openwrt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to print to the syslog (`/var/log/syslog`) you don't actually need to use `openlog()` or `closelog()`. You can see this in the [documentation for openlog from the GNU C library](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/openlog.html):

> You don't have to use openlog. If you call syslog without having called openlog, syslog just opens the connection implicitly and uses defaults for the information in ident and options

but you ***do*** need to pass the variable argument list (`...`) matching the format, otherwise `vsyslog()` won't have anything to print. Here's a working example:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <syslog.h>

void log_msg(int priority, const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list vl;

    va_start(vl, format);
    vsyslog(priority, format, vl);
    va_end(vl);
}

int main(void)
{
    log_msg(LOG_USER|LOG_DEBUG, "%d variable %s\n", 2, "arguments");
    return 0;
}
```

Then you can see the message in the syslog:

> ~/sandbox$ cat /var/log/syslog
>   ...
>   Feb 27 09:03:04  a.out: 2 variable arguments

I'm not sure what your priority is, but note the proper values are found in the [man page for `vsyslog()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/vsyslog). It's facility and the level OR'd together.

---

If you want to use `openlog()`/`closelog()` then you'll still find your messages in `/var/log/syslog`, but then they'll be appended with your name you opened. For example:

```
openlog(name, LOG_CONS, LOG_DEBUG);
va_start(vl, format);
vsyslog(priority, format, vl);
va_end(vl);
closelog();
```

(This is assuming you still pass `char * name` to the log_msg function. You'd call it as such:

```
log_msg("hello", LOG_USER|LOG_DEBUG, "%d variable %s\n", 2, "arguments");
```

Then in the `syslog` you'd now see:

> Feb 27 09:35:16 hello: 2 variable arguments

Note that the generic program name `a.out` has now changed to the name you passed to `openlog()` (`"hello"`)